# Passing how to pass multiprocessing flags in Python

Tags: python

I have a somewhat large Python program. Running it spawns multiple Processes (`multiprocessing.Process`) that communicate over various Events and Queues. I also have a growing number of command line flags (handled with argparse) that change various data paths or execution of the Processes.

Currently I put all the flags in a list and pass the list to each Processes when I create them. Not every Process uses every flag, but this approach means I just have to update the affected Processes when I add or remove a flag. However, this gets complicated as I have to remember where in each list each flag is and the different default values. I've considered making a named tuple to handle these flags or just passing the ArgumentParser.

Is these some established paradigm or Pythonic way to handle this sort of situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is *established paradigm*. However, I can't advise you a pattern that worked for me in several cases not only in Python, but in Ruby as well.

Don't store flags passed directly in the command line, parse them once and put results into object properties (you can use `namedtuple`, but it's not always best way, I prefer just my own class).

Then instead of passing all your flags into new processes, ask them to wait for configuration object in a queue and send it as first thing to every started process to hold as its configuration. Such object can be shared in different way, but that would depend on your scenarios.

Other option is to `pickle` such object and pass it as file to be loaded by every started process, or encode pickling (`base64` for example) and pass that as a single argument into the *command line* for new process.

It's hard to describe a single best pattern for your case, not knowing exactly how your code is shaped, how much is shared, etc.

Comment: Is there any benefit to sending them in a Queue as opposed to passing them at initialization?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question? If you spawn processes, they will not have THAT object; what do you mean by "at initialization" then?

Comment: You can pass objects when you create a Process. Either through the args parameter of Process or, if you're extending Process, through the call to `__init__()`.

Comment: What module you're using? `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Yes. Are there other ones? Should I edit my question?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't focused on the *topic* of the question, reading "it spawns" I focused on launching processes in more low level way.
Yes, passing this object should work as long as it can be pickled; there are several known flaws in multiprocessing (you can find them in answers here on stackoverflow).